# How do I add command line arguments (parameters) for pinned applications on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, parameters, properties, tiles

On Windows 10 I'd like to add command line arguments (parameters) for "pinned" applications in my "Start" area. But when I right click a pinned app, I don't see something like "Preferences".

Is there a way to modify the properties?

Comment: Is there a way to do this so you can have two shortcuts to the same application, one with parameters and one without. E.g. Excel application, Excel with parameters to open a document in read-only mode.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution to set a command line arguments for a pinned app:

1. Open the Start menu and **right-click the pinned app** and choose **Open file location**. Windows Explorer opens the folder containing the shortcut.
2. **Right-click** on the shortcut and choose **Properties**.
3. In the **target-field** add command line parameters after the program file name. For example: `%SystemRoot%\system32\notepad.exe C:\test1.txt`

I have tested this with Windows 10 and Windows 2012 successfully.

Comment: This does not work as long as you have both in the same directory. E.g. one link "FileZilla" with target `"C:\Program Files (x86)\FileZilla FTP Client\filezilla.exe"` and one link "FileZilla Autostart" with target `"C:\Program Files (x86)\FileZilla FTP Client\filezilla.exe" -c "0/Webserver"`. Until you delete the normal filezilla link, clicking the start menu link will open filezilla without opening the connection, after you have it deleted, you don't even have to redo the start menu association, it just works. Weird behaviour. I guess I don't want to see the code for that one...

Comment: Good work-around. I made a copy of the shortcut to provide different arguments for my application.

Comment: @Demonslay335 when I have two shortcuts it will only pin one to the windows 10 start menu. How did you get yours to work?

Comment: @SamHasler I named the shortcuts differently. Specifically, I used this for PowerShell. I have a shortcut for "PowerShell" (which defaults to v5 on Win10), and "PowerShell v2.0" that uses the "-Version 2" flag. I also altered the icons so I can tell them apart easier.